# Multiple Cells Check Without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

So, trying to explain what I need here is my two sheets on the same workbook, ***Sheet Example:***

[image]

I need to make a formula for each cell that checks Sheet A "Num_Doc_Ini" and "Num_Doc_Fin" against Sheet B "CHV_CTE_REF", calculates the total after adding up the "VL_DOC" numbers on Sheet B, and finally Checks with "correct" or "Incorrect" after comparing the result to the Sheet A "VL_DOC".

So for example, the second line of Sheet A. I need to make so that check see's the NUM_DOC_INI and FIN so "101 - 102" checks those numbers on Sheet B "CHV_CTE_REF", adds up the "VL_DOC" so in this example 4,159.86 + 4,585.1 that equals = 8,744.96, and then matches it with the "VL_DOC" on Sheet A displaying in this case the text "Correct" and If it does not match displays "Incorrect".

Some lines have few docs to reach like "106 - 108" but there are some that have 10 or more to read and sum up the values, because of that I'm really breaking my mind trying to come up with something.

Is that even possible? I can think of a few ways to use VBA for this but I'm trying to do this all with Cells Formula and because of that I am kinda lost, any help would be appreciated thanks!

Edit:
I'm using excel 2016 atm.
So here is a file for the workbook: https://mega.nz/file/LgVCBbjT#xJnf2HbHd6wdRSNPY7wXSssKv2jZ1-pMsOuKcePlulQ

And the explanation with colors:
I need on the Red Cell a formula to check the numbers of the Blue ones on sheet 1, find them on Sheet 2 (blue cells), add up the VL_DOC (Green ones) on sheet 2, and check them up against the values on Sheet 1 Orange cells (VL_DOC), then print out Correct or incorrect based on the match of the values.

Comment: Can you add the picture to the body of the question rather than the link it? Or better yet try to give a minimum reproducible example that highlights the specific problem you're facing if possible?

Comment: Sure! Here you go: https://mega.nz/file/LgVCBbjT#xJnf2HbHd6wdRSNPY7wXSssKv2jZ1-pMsOuKcePlulQ

I need on the Red Cell a formula to check the numbers of the Blue ones on sheet 1, find them on Sheet 2 (blue cells), add up the VL_DOC (Green ones) on sheet 2, and check them up against the values on Sheet 1 Orange cells (VL_DOC), then print out Correct or incorrect based on the match of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUM, INDIRECT, ADDRESS, MATCH

- Note that `INDIRECT` is a [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation) function.
- In cell `K2` of `Sheet 1` of the example workbook, you can use the following formula:

```vb
=IFERROR(IF(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(H2,Tabela1[NUM_DOC],0)+1,COLUMN(Tabela1[VL_DOC]),1,1,"Sheet 2")&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(I2,Tabela1[NUM_DOC],0)+1,COLUMN(Tabela1[VL_DOC]),1,1),TRUE))=J2,"Correct","Incorrect"),"")
```

Comment: Hi! Did you test it in the example workbook? I tried here with the formula and it shows an error message every time.

Comment: I tried in the workbook for which you provided the link. It is different than the workbook containing the worksheet which image you posted. You'll have to adjust accordingly. You have some funny worksheet names (`Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2` instead of `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`) and you have an `Excel` table called `Tabela1`. Here's a semicolon version for cell `K2` in `Sheet 1`: `=IFERROR(IF(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(H2;Tabela1[NUM_DOC];0)+1;COLUMN(Tabela1[VL_DOC]);1;1;"Sheet 2")&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(I2;Tabela1[NUM_DOC];0)+1;COLUMN(Tabela1[VL_DOC]);1;1);TRUE))=J2;"Correct";"Incorrect");"")`

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Can you upload it with your code for me to see how it's working? And Yeah i know haha, working with a bilingual company sometimes makes things a little messy.

Comment: nevermind i'm just a little dumb and forgot to change a letter haha worked perfectly thanks! Now I will change it a little to suit another project I'm doing. You really are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the link, you can use something like the below if you have the newest version of excel (where row ranges and column references are left to your specific case because we can't see them):

```
=IF(SUM(FILTER(SheetB!$VL_DOC, 
(SheetB!$CHV_CTE_REF=SheetA!J2)+(SheetB!$CHV_CTE_REF=SheetA!I2)+...))=N2, 
"Correct", "Incorrect")
```

Then add however many other conditions within the `FILTER` function you need. For example:

[image]

REQUESTED EDIT: If you don't have the newest version of excel, you can just repeatedly use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` however many times is necessary. For example:

```
=IF(SUM(
VLOOKUP($I2, SheetB!$CHV_CTE_REF, 2,),
VLOOKUP($J2, SheetB!$CHV_CTE_REF, 2,), 
...)=$N2,
"Correct", "Incorrect")
```

Comment: Hi! I'm currently using excel version 2016, will the Code change much? Here is the example sheet https://mega.nz/file/LgVCBbjT#xJnf2HbHd6wdRSNPY7wXSssKv2jZ1-pMsOuKcePlulQ If it's better for you to visualize it. The only thing that keeps me awake at night is how to put on the formula for the cell to "look up" the numbers on another sheet.

Comment: Sure thing, see my edit. Obviously remove the last comma and ellipses to run, I put them there to show that you can just keep adding in ```VLOOKUP```s for every column needed

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I get home tomorrow I'll be trying it with the full scale workbook. Will update with the results!

Comment: Hello There! I just tested it in my workbook at work, it works well when we have few columns but I have almost 1.000 columns that I need to sort out in the workbook, isn't there a way to make it automated on older versions? Just pasting the formula in each cell and it does it's thing?

Comment: The best way in that case might be to just change the data (the Number1, Number2, ..., Number1000 column) to their dollar value. Copy and paste the data to a new excel sheet, use ```=VLOOKUP(value, range, 2,0)```, copy and paste values over the old data columns, and then just use ```=IF(SUM(new_range)=dollar_column, "Correct", "Incorrect")```